# Finding automorphism group for finite fields

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, automorphism-group

There is a question about Galois Theory I found:

"Let $L$ be a field and $K$ its prime subfield. Let $\phi$ be an automorphism of $L$. Show that
$\phi$ is an automorphism of $L/K$"

All I need is to show that $\phi(a) = a $,    $ \forall a\in K$, but I don't know what properties of the prime subfield allows me to prove this.

Comment: The prime subfield is generated by $1_L$ and homomorphisms in general send identities to identities.

Comment: Where did you find this question?

Comment: What is L/K? It can't be a field. Fields don't have quotients.

Comment: @P.Lawrence: One generally studies automorphisms of field $L$ which *fix* the subfield $K$ of $L$.  So while $L/K$ is not a (ring) quotient, the notation is useful to indicate what subfield is being fixed, i.e. what subfield the automorphisms are required to be the identity automorphism on.

Comment: Yes, @P.Lawrence , you’re not the only one who has complained about the archaic notation $L/K$. When I was a boy, it was standard, but when someone in an algebra class of mine misunderstood, I changed to writing $L\supset K$ instead. What you see very often nowadays is $L|K$. Of course the explanation of the old notation was, I suppose, just that it was shorthand for “$L$ over $K$”, as we’ve been drawing pictures with $L$ above $K$ since time immemorial.

Comment: @Lubin .This is surprising that $L/K$ isn't standard notation. I am currently using it in most maths subjects which contain field theory, and as long as it clearly doesn't concern quotients, then there isn't much ambiguity.

Comment: It’s an unnecessary confusion for beginners, @qwertycheese7463 . Maybe I went overboard in calling it archaic, but as I said, I don’t use it, even among equally superannuated mathematicians as I.

Comment: It's strange because I'm very new to Galois theory and this is how it's currently taught to me. I think there is less confusion given that you would never consider a "quotient field" so this shouldn't cause too much confusion. Also especially when you use letter $L$,$K$,$M$ which are rarely used when talking about more general rings. Indeed whenever I read $L:M$ that is confusing to me.